# How can I gather wake lock information of my app?

Tags: android, linux, wakelock

I want to gather wake lock information from my app. Perfect will be a stack trace, periodicity and time of all wake locks produced of my app. I tried to read content of

```
/proc/wakelocks
```

and

```
/sys/kernel/debug/wakeup_sources
```

But this information isn't enough and I found that this files is missing on some devices. Any ideas? Did someone work with this?

**Update**

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector
for example how this app works?

**Update 2**

So I found a solution for this. Using reflection I can find instance of BatteryStats class where all needed information. But problem is this wasn't work on Android 4.4 and later as Google changed permissions.